# Responsive images vs Lighthouse performance audit

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, lighthouse

I'm working with a responsive design and Lighthouse keeps telling me "**Image elements do not have explicit width and height**". I concluded that it means *in the html*, because my images have set dimensions in my css with different breakpoints.

Is there a best practice here to keep being responsive but make Lighthouse happy? It might be obvious, but as a student, I'm scratching my head here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right that's actually the best practice and that is recommended for Web Vitals to enhance performance.

If you set height and width, the space required for the image is reserved when the page is loaded. However, without these attributes, the browser does not know the size of the image, and cannot reserve the appropriate space to it.

when you add img in general you should add in html width and height and I prefer to add values that I am adding in CSS or sometimes when I don't have values in CSS I'm doing inspect on the element and make the browser tell me width and height then I back to html and write them.

if you are interested in this topic (Performance) search about Web Vitals ([Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/optimize-cls/#:%7E:text=History%20%23,minimize%20reflow%20and%20re%2Dlayout.&text=You%20may%20notice%20width%20and%20height%20above%20do%20not%20include%20units.)) you will find interesting topics

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure how to keep my images responsive, aside from adding inline style for my breakpoints, which seems... completely contrary to everything I've heard from my teachers.

Comment: If you want the image to scale both up and down on responsiveness, set the CSS width property to 100% and height to auto:
```.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}```

If you want an image to scale down if it has to, but never scale up to be larger than its original size, use max-width: 100%

```.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}```

If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice:

```.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Also, I recommend for you to add object-fit:cover :

```.responsive_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* Prevent the image from stretching. So it crops the image to prevent from awkward stretching */
}```